# Problem importing a MariaDB table with a BEFORE INSERT trigger

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am struggling to find an simple solution to import a table that has a "before insert" trigger. When importing the table, the trigger fires at each row that is imported, wreaking havoc in the table.

That trigger is supposed to create an incremental unique ID each time we create a new row (it is an idea of the type "yy_mm_dd".incremental_integer_for_the_day, and I have found no other way to get MariaDB to create it).

Is there a better way than deleting the trigger in both the exporting and receiving databases, doing the import, and then recreating manually the trigger???

Thanks!
E.

Comment: I think you have to drop the trigger and recreate it.  However, you might consider using just an auto-incremented column, storing the date separately, so you don't need a trigger.

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, it does work if I manually edit the export file, to move the creation triggers after the insertion of the rows, leaving the drop trigger where it is (i.e. before the rows to import). SO that is a solution, although it does require some manual edit with my SQL software (Querious) which generates an export script with the triggers at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks!

Yes, it does work if I manually edit the export file, to move the creation triggers after the insertion of the rows, leaving the drop trigger where it is (i.e. before the rows to import). So that is a solution, although it does require some manual edit with my SQL software (Querious) which generates an export script with the triggers at the beginning.

And your suggestion to create two columns, one with the date and the other with the increment may be one to explore. Although since I have to reset the increment each period (day in my example), it would still require another trigger, or some PHP code.

What I wanted to avoid with the trigger was the sql request to retrieve the max(ID), increment it (or in your second solution the max(date) and the max(id in the period), check if first row of day, then reset to 1 or increment) and another request to save the ID value...

There does not seem to be a way to disable the triggers during the import, as there is to disable the foreign key check.

E.